# Json.net can not install in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, nuget, nuget-package

when i am installing Newtonsoft.json using Nugget package manager then i am getting error like this

[image]

i am having .net framework version 4.5.50709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your nuget manager to 2.6 and restart visual studio.